# How do i replace a setTimeout function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I want to set a timeout to go off X amount of seconds from now. If X changes, I want to clear the timeout and start a new timeout based on the new value of X. When I try to clear timeout it wont work. Here is my code

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (this.props.expirationTimeout !== nextProps.expirationTimeout) {
      this.setState({ 
          expirationTimeout: nextProps.expirationTimeout 
      });
      window.clearTimeout(this.setExpiration);
      this.setExpiration(nextProps.expirationTimeout);
    }
}

setExpiration(time) {
    let timeouts = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < timeouts.length; i++) {
      clearTimeout(timeouts[i]);
    }
    var t = time - new Date().getTime();
    timeouts.push(setTimeout(this.state.logoutUserAndRedirect, t));
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. to use `clearTimeout()` you need id that `setTimeout` returned before
2. currently result of `setTimeout` with id of timer is stored into block-level variable `timeouts`. So there is no chance to use it for `clearTimeout` in `componentWillReceiveProps`.
3. Since every single change into state triggers re-rendering I suggest not storing `props.expirationTimeout` value into state. The same is for `logoutUserAndRedirect`. There is no sense to keep it in `state`.
4. what if new value of timer is less than previous? what if according to new value you have already missed the time to do what you plan? `setTimeout` will work this way if it gets delay value < 0. Is not it great? :)
5. [UPD] also I believe it's needed to store timestamp when recent timeout has started. This way we would be able to correct it later after delay value is changed.

   ```
   componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
       if (this.props.expirationTimeout !== nextProps.expirationTimeout) {
           this.modifyExpiration(this.timerStartedAt + nextProps.expirationTimeout - this.props.expiration);
       }
   }

   modifyExpiration(time) {
       this.timeoutId && clearTimeout(this.timeoutId);
       this.timeoutId = setTimeout(this.logoutUserAndRedirect, time);
       this.timerStartedAt = +new Date();
   }
   ```